# Что лучше: Redis, Consul, etcd для key-value?

Tags: redis

Интересует не скорость а удобство работы и возможность создать кластер из таких хранилищ. 
Основное это права доступа: чтобы можно было разграничивать право на запись или чтение. 
Может кто сталаивплся с этим? Было бы интересно послушать опыт.

Answer (score 5):

Если отбросить тот факт, что etcd обычно используется для хранения конфигов, consul - это сервис дискавери тулза по большей части, а Redis - полноценная база данных, то...

1. consul удобен, прост, надёжен. Я его использовал в течение 4 лет. Один раз настроить мастер ноды, а агентские ноды легко потом подключать. Если вы умеете пользоваться чем-нибудь типо Ansible, то с помощью готовых плейбуков вообще легко всё настроить.
2. Redis хорош. Кластер/сентинель редиса не так хорош. Хотя, кластеризацию они в последние годы прокачали. Но, опять же, если вам нужно хранить только конфиги, то Redis - оверхед.
3. etcd пользовал для k8s. В то время он периодически падал. Сейчас вроде вполне стабилен.

**TL;DR:** для конфигов я бы рекомендовал consul, там ещё в придачу и сервис дискавери будет и возможность локальный DNS настроить. У него единственного, насколько я помню, хорошо сделан ACL, чтоб права раздавать удобно было. Плюс, Vault сбоку прикрутить можно.

Если нужно много всякого хранить, то лучше Redis, как полноценную базу использовать. Ну, можно ещё Касандру.